$f$ and $Df$ are not relative primes in $F[X]$, then they are not relative primes in $K[X]$.
The question I will ask originates in the context of the theory of perfect fields and separable extensions, but it is a question of irreducibility of polynomials between extensions of fields and of relative prime polynomials.
In my field theory and galois course, we were introduced to the following lemma for the development of field theory:
If $f\in K[X]$ is a polynomial such that $Df(X)\neq 0$ (the formal derivative), then the following are equivalent:

The roots of $f$ are all simple.
$f$ and $Df(x)$ are relative primes.

Let us consider $F/K$ where $F$ is the splitting field of the polynomial $f$.
By doing 2) implies 1), in my university notes a reduction to the absurd is made with which we arrive at the fact that $f$ and $Df$ are not relative primes in $F[X]$, "and therefore they are not relative primes in $K[X]$".
Ii is clear that if the are not relative primes in $K[X]$, then they are also not relative primes in $F[X]$, which is used in 1)$\Rightarrow$2), but why does the other implication used in 2)$\Rightarrow$1) also hold?
